# BigQuery GA360 export - product query

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm working through the documentation with BigQuery, and I'm stuck on a particular query.

```
SELECT hits.item.productName AS other_purchased_products, COUNT(hits.item.productName) AS quantity
FROM [XXXXXXX.ga_sessions_20171101]
WHERE fullVisitorId IN (
  SELECT fullVisitorId
  FROM [XXXXXXXX.ga_sessions_20171101]
  WHERE hits.item.productName CONTAINS 'Product A'
   AND totals.transactions>=1
  GROUP BY fullVisitorId )
 AND hits.item.productName IS NOT NULL
 AND hits.item.productName !='Product A'
GROUP BY other_purchased_products
ORDER BY quantity DESC;
```

This one works fine for an individual day in the dataset, however If I want to use TABLE DATE RANGE it errors.

To use the above query across multiple dates, how do I adjust this?

Thanks

Comment: If you are learning BigQuery, you should focus on the standard SQL dialect, instead of legacy SQL.

Comment: You can also [sign up for a preview of the new BigQuery UI](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSf6hyfvoWZ8eUbbKWq9fzVfj7ljVyl2SdhtWH038Xrx2eHVrw/viewform), which uses standard SQL by default.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard - Elliott - how it works? I did signed up  - but have no any feedback!

Comment: Hmm do you mean that you signed up just now, or was it a while ago? I think it's kind of a manual process where one of our PMs enables access for the requested projects from the form.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard - did this few days ago - any recommendation?

Comment: I'll ping our PM who is in charge of the process to update the list of projects.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard - Thank you Elliott! :o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With legacy SQL the only way is to use an `INNER JOIN` on fullvisitorid